Delphi Dev Express TcxDBTimeEdit and how to handle nulls?
Delphi Dev Express TcxDBTimeEdit and how to handle nulls ?
I'm trying to use Dev Express TcxDBTimeEdit component in Delphi and I'm keen for user to be able to use mouse to select all and delete key to clear and for this to store a null in the associated database column field value.
I'm not sure how to achieve this.
I have tried this, but it doesn't work, in the component Exit event:
    if
       (cxDBTimeEdit1.Text = '00:00 AM')
       or (cxDBTimeEdit1.Text = '12:00 AM')
       or (cxDBTimeEdit1.Text = '')
    then dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsString:='';

I'm also using an old version of Delphi .. Delphi 2007 and also old version of Dev Express components .. version 6.50 from April 2009.
Am connecting via Devart SDAC 8.2.9 to MS SQL Server 2017 DB
I did finally get this working with some quite unusual events code:
procedure TfrmC420201ClaimLine.tedTimeOfServiceKeyDown(Sender: TObject;
      var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    begin
      inherited;
      //This code allows the operator to select the time and press the delete key to return the DB col value to NULL
      //The SetFocus on another control and unassign and then reassign DataField is required to achieve this. Looks odd but works.
      if Key = VK_DELETE then
      begin
        tedTimeOfService.DataBinding.DataField:='';
        with dmClaimLine do
        begin
            if (FMode <> 'Assess') then Exit;
            ClaimLineEditable;
            dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.Clear;
            dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsString:='';
        end;
        edtMediTimeDuration.SetFocus;
        tedTimeOfService.DataBinding.DataField:='TimeOfService';
      end;
    
    end;

procedure TfrmC420201ClaimLine.tedTimeOfServiceEnter(Sender: TObject);
begin
    inherited;

    with dmClaimLine do
    begin
        if (FMode <> 'Assess') then Exit;
        ClaimLineEditable;
        dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsDateTime := tedTimeOfService.Time        
    end;

end;

procedure TfrmC420201ClaimLine.tedTimeOfServicePropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
var EditValueStr, TimeStr: string;
begin
    inherited;
    if VarIsNull(tedTimeOfService.EditValue) then EditValueStr  := 'Null' else EditValueStr  := TimeToStr(tedTimeOfService.Time);
    if VarIsNull(tedTimeOfService.Time) then TimeStr := 'Null' else TimeStr := TimeToStr(tedTimeOfService.Time);

    with dmClaimLine do
    begin
        if (FMode <> 'Assess') then Exit;
        if (dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsString = '')
        and (EditValueStr = 'Null') then exit;
        if dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsDateTime <> tedTimeOfService.Time
        then
        begin
            ClaimLineEditable;
            dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsDateTime := tedTimeOfService.Time
        end;
    end;
end;


Did you try setting the value to null, eg: cxDBTimeEdit1.EditValue := Null ? What is the declaration for qryClaimLineTimeOfService ?

Your question doesn't specify what database components you're using and what database type (Interbase, Firebird, MS SQL, other) or whether you indent to make a database column null by using a TTable type data access pattern or a TQuery type data access pattern (update TABLE set X = :y).

AsString := '' is wrong, and so is checking to see if it's equal to ''. Use Clear and IsNull respectively.

Like all TcxDB components,TcxDBTimeEdit  needs a datasource and the field name for a (in this case nullable) time field in your database. Does your DB support those?

Your code is working directly with the control state instead of the database state.
You should instead try to handle things using the actual underlying field in the underlying dataset.
The fact that your control is a cxDBTimeEdit is not even important to your question.
dmClaimLine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService.AsString:='';

^^ Whatever you think this does, it probably doesn't do it.^^
If you are using a dataset to directly edit row values you need to specify how you're doing that. how you do that differs depending on the component set you use to access a database, and the database you're connecting to, you haven't specified either one.
You're coding against the visual controls [cxDBTimeEdit1.Text], when you should be reading the field values from the database access components (DAC).  If you were using ADO, for instance, and you had an ADOTable named ClaimLine, you might be needing to do this
ClaimLine.Edit;
ClaimLineTimeOfService.Clear; // make a field null
ClaimLine.Post;

If you were instead updating with an SQL update statement you might do something like this
UpdateClaimEntry.ParamByName('timeofservice').Clear;
UpdateClaimEntry.ExecSQL;


The OP is not coding against the visual controls.  dmClaimLiine.qryClaimLineTimeOfService is a persistent field in a datamodule. Visual controls do not have AsString methods. You got the relevant part right about using Clear instead, though. :-)

The OP is coding against the visual controls in the other lines. By the time the Exit event is reached, checking their content is incorrect. the TYPE of qryClaimLine and its content (is it a select query? update?) is unclear.  The db controls being used are specified (but irrelevant).  The DAC component types in use and their content (what sql statements) are not specified, and ARE relevant.
They need to clear a TField or clear a Param, depending on whether they have TABLE or UPDATESQL methods for updating a db row.  checking the cxDBEdit state is incorrect.

qryClaimLineTimeOfService is a TField for sure but is it a TField on a select statement? If so, how is it updating the content inside the db? Most DACs don't have that feature.

@allanf Given what Warren wrote, can you change your interface such that clearing the field can be done differently, e.g. a button labeled Clear next to the time editor? You can then execute the correct SQL to null the field in the DB.
